# Finding the Length of the Diagonals of a Kite

Tags: geometry

The question is as follows:

> A kite has an 8-inch side and a 15-inch side, which form a right angle. Find the length of the diagonals of the kite.

I found the length of the vertical diagonal to be 17in, but I can't find the length of the horizontal diagonal. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: find two **similar** right-angled triangles, one with a 17-inch hypotenuse and one with a 15-inch hypotenuse. You know all the sides of the larger triangle, so you can calculate the sides of the smaller one.

Comment: @RobArthan I think I found the two similar right-angled triangles, and I am guessing that I can correspond the 8-inch side of the 17-inch hypotenuse triangle, with the unknown value of the side. If I do $17 \div 15$, I get a decimal answer, therefore, I am unsure if this is what I should be doing.

Comment: You can write the answer as a fraction.

Comment: I get the side in the 15-inch hypotenuse triangle to be $\approx 7.06$. So if I double it then it would be 14.12-inch. Is this right?

Comment: I'm not marking your homework. If this was a puzzle in a newspaper, I'd give the answer as a fraction (like $42/99$). I can't help you any more with the desired format of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One diagonal can by found by pythagoras, $a^2+b^2=c^2$. Then the other can be found by expressing the area of a right triangle in two ways: $\frac12ab=\frac 12ch$.

Comment: I am unsure by what meant with $\frac12ab=\frac 12ch$ and would like to clarify.